# WCF One Way Call - Timeout exception thrown, but message still queued and processed - why/how to abort?

Tags: wcf

I have a very simple WCF one way service (hosted in IIS) it is using basicHttpBinding:

```
        <service name="OptumRx.Formulary.ServiceLayer.UserRequestService" behaviorConfiguration="UserRequestBehaviors">
            <endpoint
                address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAuthBinding"
                contract="OptumRx.Formulary.ServiceLayer.IUserRequestService">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="....."
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAuthBinding"
                  contract="OptumRx.Formulary.ServiceLayer.IUserRequestService">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WindowsAuthBinding" sendTimeout="00:00:15" >
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="UserRequestBehaviors">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2" maxConcurrentInstances="2"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
```

Code snippits:

```
    // interface, declarying one way contract
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SubmitUserRequest(RequestServiceObject request);

// setting per call instancing and multiple concurrency
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
                InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class UserRequestService : IUserRequestService {
}

    // how the client calls the service (client is asp.net page hosted within same site as service)
    ChannelFactory<IUserRequestService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IUserRequestService>("*");
    IUserRequestService proxyUserRequest = factory.CreateChannel();
    try {
      proxyUserRequest.SubmitUserRequest(so);
    } catch {
      // timeout error caught
    } finally {
      ((IClientChannel)proxyUserRequest).Close();
      factory.Close();
    }
```

The call does some potentially heavy database/IO work and we may want to throttle the max concurrent calls. If we've reached that throttle is there anyway to stop calls from getting queued?

With the above configuration, 2 calls get processed and the third one timesout (exception is thrown and caught). In the Service Trace Viewier I even see:

```
 The system hit the limit set for throttle 'MaxConcurrentCalls'. Limit for this throttle was set to 2. ....

 The HTTP request to '' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:15. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

But once the first 2 calls complete, the 3rd message still exists in the listener channel I guess and gets executed.

Is there any way to abort the call while still using one way configuration? I would want  the user to know the service was "busy" and to try again later.. .

Thank you